# How do you find empty pages in a pdf?

Tags: python, pdf

Let's say I have a pdf called Test-001.pdf, and in Test-001.pdf, and there are 16 pages.

For all the pages in Test-001.pdf, I want to check them and see if one (or multiple) pages are empty.

```
import PyPdf4

def empty_page(dest='/Users/Harold882/Downloads/test_folder/Test-001.pdf'):
    with open(dest, 'wb') as f:
        reader = PyPDF4.PdfFileReader(f)
        writer = PyPDF4.PdfFileWriter
        for page in range(reader.getNumPages()):
            new_page = reader.getPage(page)
```

I've only worked up to there because I don't know how to say "if new_page is empty, delete new_page" or something like that.

How can you delete empty pages using PyPdf4?

Comment: How does an empty page look?

Comment: No text, no images, basically no content

Comment: I get that an empty pdf page contains no text, image, etc.  What I was asking is what does the variable ```page``` return for an empty pdf page.

Comment: it returns nothing?

Comment: aw man, that sucks